# How to have separate captions in the same level in the minipage environment with listing?

Tags: latex, listings

In the minipage environment with listing and figure I'd like to have three separate captions `a`, `b`, `c` **evenly** as the picture below:

[image]

But my try with this minimal code results an **untidy** captions as below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
   while(a < 0){
   a++;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{C program}
\end{minipage}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
    &F_1(a, b) \leftarrow a \le 0 \\ 
    &F_2(a, b) \leftarrow  F_1(a, b) \\ 
    \end{align*}
    \caption{Automata}
\end{minipage}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Relation}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{overal blablablablablabla  caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get rid of `Figure` keyword and get `a`, `b`, `c` caption in the same level?

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `[b]`ottom align your minipages:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
   while(a < 0){
   a++;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{C program}
\end{minipage}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
    &F_1(a, b) \leftarrow a \le 0 \\ 
    &F_2(a, b) \leftarrow  F_1(a, b) \\ 
    \end{align*}
    \caption{Automata}
\end{minipage}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Relation}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same technique works also with `subfigure`s:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\noindent\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
   while(a < 0){
   a++;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{C program}
\end{subfigure}%
\noindent\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
    &F_1(a, b) \leftarrow a \le 0 \\ 
    &F_2(a, b) \leftarrow  F_1(a, b) \\ 
    \end{align*}
    \caption{Automata}
\end{subfigure}%
\noindent\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Relation}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, How about the first part of question: " How can I get rid of Figure keyword to have a, b, c  in the middle captions like in the first picture"?

Comment: @sepideha The `subcaption` package

Comment: I tried `\subcaption{\textsl{(a)text}\label{fig:sub:subfigure1}}` with `\usepackage{subcaption}` but didn't manage to fix the compilation error: Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation(subcaption) with the subfigure package. \subcaption@CheckCompatibility

Comment: The code in your question does not load the `subfigure` package :) You an also use this, but personally I find subcaption easier to use.

Comment: I updated my answer to show an example with `subcaption`

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried also with my minimal example worked fine. I will figure out with which other package it conflicts?

Comment: you could ask a new question to find the package conflict if you manage to show the code necessary to reproduce the problem.